# Filter one list using index value obtained from another list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I've got one list which contains string

```
List<string> valueList = new List<string>();

valueList.Add("test1");
valueList.Add("test2");
valueList.Add("test3");
valueList.Add("test4");
valueList.Add("test5");
valueList.Add("test6");
valueList.Add("test7");
valueList.Add("test8");
```

and I've got another list which contains objects

```
List<test> fieldList = new List<test>();
fieldList.Add(new test() { FieldName = "field1", FieldType = 1, FieldIndex = 0 });
fieldList.Add(new test() { FieldName = "field3", FieldType = 1, FieldIndex = 2 });
fieldList.Add(new test() { FieldName = "field5", FieldType = 1, FieldIndex = 4 });
```

I want to use the FieldIndex property from the object contained in fieldList, so I build a list which just contains the fieldIndex values using the following

```
var mylist = fieldList.Select(m => m.FieldIndex).ToList();
```

But now I'd like to use that list of `fieldindex` to retrieve the values from `valuelist`, so based on the above `myList` will contain test1, test3 and test5 and ideally I'd like to end up with a string a comma between each i.e. `string values = "test1,test3,test5"`

I'm sure there has to be a way of doing this using linq, but can't figure out how!

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = String.Join(",", valueList
    .Where(vl => fieldList.Select(fl => fl.FieldIndex)
                          .Contains(valueList.IndexOf(vl))))
```

Comment: Pure class!!! Thanks so much! I hate the fact that I wasted some much time trying to figure it out myself but I guess that's how you learn!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution

```
 var mylist = fieldList.Select(m => m.FieldIndex).ToList();
 string str = string.Empty;
 mylist.ForEach((i) => str += valueList[i] + ",");
```